# Wso2 carbon/apimgt open source code download

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have downloaded the wso2 open source of master branch from github, but the build is failing.  Can anyone guide me in the right direction?  How do I get the publisher and store of wso2 api mananager up?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you install nodejs and java8(or higher) to your computer. you can try with any version after checking out to the particular tag or if you want the latest release pack, go with the master branch. First build the carbon repo(https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt) and  after you build the carbon repo then take the version(it's in main pom file()) of that and update carbon version(<carbon.apimgt.version>) of the product-apim(https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/) main pom file(it's already included a carbon version, replace it to your version). Then build the product-apim.

Comment: i have installed nodejs and java8 in my Computer then i have  downloaded wso2/carbon-apimgt master branch . Still build is getting failed  for wso2/carbon-apimgt..Please guide how to start publisher and store UI from wso2 open source code.

Comment: [ERROR] /C:/Users/syedt/Downloads/carbon-apimgt-6/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1/src/gen/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/rest/api/store/impl/v1/TagsApiServiceImpl.java:[20,8] duplicate class: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1.impl.TagsApiServiceImpl

Comment: [ERROR] /C:/Users/syedt/Downloads/carbon-apimgt-6/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/rest/api/store/v1/impl/SelfSignupApiServiceImpl.java:[27,8] duplicate class: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1.impl.SelfSignupApiServiceImpl

Comment: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) on project org.wso2.carbon.am.integration.backend.test: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete C:\Users\syedt\Downloads\product-apim-master\modules\integration\tests-integration\tests-backend\target\carbontmp1596552730909\wso2am-3.2.0-SNAPSHOT\tmp\axis2-tmp-8723377489328634931.tmp\axis2818449858380134918addressing-1.6.1-wso2v41.mar ->

Comment: I'm getting above errors for  wso2 carbon and product for master branch or any specific version  .Please guide me how to get the build sucess for wso2 carbon and product master branch

Comment: can you skip test and run again  **mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -DskipTests** since you do not need to run the tests to build. if it's failed again delete .m2 folder and build again. (it's located in C:\Users\{your-username}\.m2)

Comment: i ran by  skipping test cases still build is getting failed.

Comment: can you delete the .m2 folder and build again ? for windows it's located in C:\Users\{your-username}\.m2

Comment: i have deleted m2 folder and ran build,still build is getting failed.

Comment: Maybe this can happen because of admin privileges in windows. Just close your command prompt and again run it as Administrator and execute the maven command.

Comment: Are you trying to build the master branch or v6.6.163? Seems to me that the code you are trying to build might be corrupted. Can you please clone the repo (either master or tag v6.6.163) to a new location and try what Chashika has mentioned?

Comment: I tried with master branch by making command prompt as Administrator.Still build is getting failed.Thank You..

Comment: Still, get the same issue or different issues?

Answer (score 0):

The master branch is the ongoing development branch. Hence could you please refer this link [1] to get start the WSO2 APIM. This will guide you on how to start publisher and developer portals.
[1]. https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/getting-started/quick-start-guide

Comment: Actually i want to the customize the wso2 open source code i.e wso2/carbon/apimgt . .After downloading the code from the github  build is getting failed.Please suggest how to proceed with the wso2 open source code. https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt

Comment: Please check out WSO2 apim 3.1.0 from https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/find/v6.6.163 , https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/tree/v3.1.0 repos and build a pack.

Comment: im unable to find  carbon code with v6.6.163 .I have checkout https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/tree/v6  code  still build is getting failed.From wso2 open source  code how we will make publisher and store url up.

Comment: Please use this url: https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/tree/v6.6.163

Comment: First you should build the https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/tree/v6.6.163. Then you have to build the github.com/wso2/product-apim/tree/v3.1.0
 After successfully build those repositories. Extract the APIM 3.1.0 distribution from 
/Users/hasunie/RD/UI/product-apim/modules/distribution/product/target/
Then you can extract the distribution zip file and run the product

Comment: build is getting failed for wso2/carbon-apimgt/tree/v6.6.163  can anyone   suggest which version of wso2 carbon open source  can be useful for customizing .

Answer (score 0):

What is the maven version you have in your windows machine? When working with windows it is highly suggested to use compatible versions rather than the latest versions.